# removed MessageSelector in Symfony/Component/Translation

Tags: symfony, service, translation, selector, symfony5

I just tried to upgrade to Symfony 5.0, however, I get the following error:

```
You have requested a non-existent service "translator.selector".
```

In my code in services.yaml I have

```
Symfony\Component\Translation\MessageSelector: '@translator.selector'
```

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/Translation/CHANGELOG.md I saw that it was removed. How should I continue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best way is to check the Changelog https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/UPGRADE-5.0.md

> The MessageSelector, Interval and PluralizationRules classes have been removed, use IdentityTranslator instead

Comment: How should I change '@translator.selector', because that is still a non-existing service, even after changing MessageSelector to IdentityTranslator?     Edit:  should be changed to `translator.formatter.default`. Thanks!